# How to make AppBar component from material-ui-next react to scroll events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, appbar

As per [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#behavior):

> Upon scrolling, the top app bar can […] transform in the following ways:
>   - Scrolling upward hides the top app bar
>   - Scrolling downward reveals the top app bar
>   When the top app bar scrolls, its elevation above other elements becomes apparent.

Is there any built-in approach to do this in material-ui-next or should it be considered as a new feature? Can you give a hint on how to achieve the animation of the AppBar component as described in the guidelines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who are still looking for built-in feature, [Hide appbar on scroll](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#hide-app-bar) is available in `material-ui`.

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge, there's no out-of-the-box solution for this at the moment. It's quite easy to implement though. Here is a snippet that subscribes to scroll events and hides or shows the AppBar accordingly:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  show: {
    transform: 'translateY(0)',
    transition: 'transform .5s',
  },
  hide: {
    transform: 'translateY(-110%)',
    transition: 'transform .5s',
  },
};

class CollapsibleAppBar extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      shouldShow: null,
    };

    this.lastScroll = null;

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    // Alternatively, you can throttle scroll events to avoid
    // updating the state too often. Here using lodash.
    // this.handleScroll = _.throttle(this.handleScroll.bind(this), 100);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, { passive: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll(evt) {
    const lastScroll = window.scrollY;

    if (lastScroll === this.lastScroll) {
      return;
    }

    const shouldShow = (this.lastScroll !== null) ?  (lastScroll < this.lastScroll) : null;

    if (shouldShow !== this.state.shouldShow) {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        ...prevState,
        shouldShow,
      }));
    }

    this.lastScroll = lastScroll;
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <AppBar
      position="fixed"
      color="default"
      className={
            `${classes.root} ${
              this.state.shouldShow === null ? '' : (
                this.state.shouldShow ? classes.show : classes.hide
              )
            }`
          }
    >
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
              Title
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

CollapsibleAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CollapsibleAppBar);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Here is a demo which implements your solution with the current version of Material-UI (v1): https://codesandbox.io/s/4z56yl6rm4

Answer (score 7):

in the current version of Material-ui, you can simply use the following

```
import clsx from "clsx";
import useScrollTrigger from "@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger";
const trigger = useScrollTrigger();

<AppBar className={trigger ? classes.show : classes.hide}>
</AppBar>
```

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger

Comment: Is there an example for the same using the new version?

Comment: slighlty sketchy as it takes some time to disappear. it just triggers on top and bottom which means if you are too low on the page, the header will still popup

Answer (score 0):

this seem to work for me

```
import {
  useScrollTrigger,
  Fab,
  Zoom,
} from '@mui/material';
```

...

```
function ElevationScroll(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const theme = useTheme();
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0,
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    sx: trigger
      ? {
          bgcolor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
          'transition-duration': '500ms',
          'transition-property':
            'padding-top, padding-bottom, background-color',
          'transition-timing-function': 'ease-in-out',
        }
      : {
          pt: 2,
          pb: 2,
          bgcolor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        },
    elevation: trigger ? 5 : 0,
  });
}

function ScrollTop(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 200,
  });

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const anchor = (event.target.ownerDocument || document).querySelector(
      '#back-to-top-anchor'
    );

    if (anchor) {
      anchor.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Zoom in={trigger}>
      <Box
        onClick={handleClick}
        role="presentation"
        sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 16, right: 16, zIndex: 1 }}
      >
        {children}
      </Box>
    </Zoom>
  );
}
```

...

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar position="sticky">
        ...
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <Toolbar
        id="back-to-top-anchor"
        className="_Toolbar"
        sx={{
          minHeight: '0 !important',
        }}
      />
      <ScrollTop {...props}>
        <Fab color="secondary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
          <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
        </Fab>
      </ScrollTop>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seem to work for me

```
import {
  useScrollTrigger,
  Fab,
  Zoom,
} from '@mui/material';
```

...

```
function ElevationScroll(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const theme = useTheme();
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0,
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    sx: trigger
      ? {
          bgcolor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
          'transition-duration': '500ms',
          'transition-property':
            'padding-top, padding-bottom, background-color',
          'transition-timing-function': 'ease-in-out',
        }
      : {
          pt: 2,
          pb: 2,
          bgcolor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        },
    elevation: trigger ? 5 : 0,
  });
}

function ScrollTop(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 200,
  });

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const anchor = (event.target.ownerDocument || document).querySelector(
      '#back-to-top-anchor'
    );

    if (anchor) {
      anchor.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Zoom in={trigger}>
      <Box
        onClick={handleClick}
        role="presentation"
        sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 16, right: 16, zIndex: 1 }}
      >
        {children}
      </Box>
    </Zoom>
  );
}
```

...

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar position="sticky">
        ...
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <Toolbar
        id="back-to-top-anchor"
        className="_Toolbar"
        sx={{
          minHeight: '0 !important',
        }}
      />
      <ScrollTop {...props}>
        <Fab color="secondary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
          <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
        </Fab>
      </ScrollTop>
    </React.Fragment>
```

https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger