# How to autohide AppBar when scrolling using Reactjs Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, scroll, material-design, material-ui

How can I autohide my Reactjs `<AppBar/>` component when scrolling as shown in Fig.1?

Fig.1. `<AppBar/>` autohides when scrolling

[image]

[I am using Material-UI and my code is as follows.](https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/)

MyAppBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make AppBar component from material-ui-next react to scroll events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567790/how-to-make-appbar-component-from-material-ui-next-react-to-scroll-events)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Slide`](https://material-ui.com/api/slide/) in conjuction with [`useScrollTrigger`](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger)

The gist here is, `useScrollTrigger` will (by default) return `true` when you scroll down and the window vertical scrollbar position hits a certain threshold (`100` pixels from origin by default) - when you scroll back up it returns `false`. Hence, these are the reasons why we negate it on the `in` prop of `Slide`

```
export default function HideAppBar() {
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger();

  return (
    <>        
      <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">Scroll Down to Hide App Bar</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Slide>    
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

You can use the link I gave at the top of this answer pertaining to `useScrollTrigger` to customize the options such as `threshold`

Reference: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#hide-app-bar